# Aeron: should Archive taggedReplicate work with C Media Driver?

Tags: java, high-availability, low-latency, aeron

I'm getting [a timeout exception](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/blob/master/aeron-archive/src/main/java/io/aeron/archive/ReplicationSession.java#L514-L516) on my even basic tests with [taggedReplicate](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/blob/master/aeron-archive/src/main/java/io/aeron/archive/client/AeronArchive.java#L1582), while with Java MD everything is just fine.

I tested with a stand alone MD versions 1.27.0 and 1.31.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Archive tagged replicate does work with both the Java and C media drivers. It is possible you have something not configured correctly. This [system test](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/blob/1.31.1/aeron-system-tests/src/test/java/io/aeron/archive/ReplicateRecordingTest.java#L496)
runs against the Java and C media drivers.